# Adding division to current formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have my Excel formula found below does this:

**Scenario**:

I have three products, product A, product B and product C. I want to be able quickly to calculate the actual revenue. The data structure is in the image. My top-most row is month. For each month I have four columns, of which two need to be calculated should the condition match.

This is the condition. An example, for product A, calculate the total sumproduct (multiplies column actual customers x Price Actuals) for yearMonth 201501.

So basically, first, for product A, it would need to find YearMonth 201501, and when it is found, it should find columns Actual Customers and Price Actuals and return the SUMPRODUCT of Actual Customers and Price Actuals.

**Modification help**

I want the formula to divide at the end with the total amount of customers for that specific product and month. How can I do that?

Here is the workbook. [Workbook](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=FE479525195477F7!3477&ithint=file%2Cxlsx&app=Excel&authkey=!AG_gKA_8TBXmpXE)

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$I$5*($B$1:$I$1=TheMonth)*(($B$2:$I$2="Actual Customers")+($B$2:$I$2="Price - Actuals"))*($A$3:$A$5=TheProduct))
```

Comment: Your sample workbook calculates sum of `actual customers` and `Price Actuals` not the product. Are you sure the current formula is OK?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by *'total amount of customers'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the amount of customers for that month and product, you can just modify that sumproduct function to get this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$I$5*($B$1:$I$1=TheMonth)*(($B$2:$I$2="Actual Customers")*($A$3:$A$5=TheProduct)))
```

That (for me) returned the value 56 for **p C** and 1951 for **p b**, so I'm pretty sure you would just have to do *formula1/formula2* to get what you want (where *formula1* is your original formula and *formula2* is the one I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understood your question but as far as I got it, and following your file, for product A (pA) you would like to have the following:

D3*F3 = 1064?

Is that right?

If it is, I don't see the reason for using the sumproduct function. You could just add a new Actual Revenue column in between each month and compute it for each row.

If I am wrong in my understanding, please elaborate with an example of what you would like to do (please use the same simple computational description I showed above).